# backAndroid/backHandler working for every screen--React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have enabled backandroid to show logout alert in home screen. Problem is even though screen navigated away from home screen. still Logout alert coming. basic back navigation is also disabled.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
 componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._handleback);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    //Forgetting to remove the listener will cause pop executes multiple times
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._handleback);
}

 _handleback = () => {

    Alert.alert(i18N.t('alertHeader'), i18N.t('logoutqHeader'), [
        {
            text: i18N.t('yes'), onPress: () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('login'); }
        },
        { text: i18N.t('cancel'), onPress: () => { return true; }, style: 'cancel' },

    ], { cancelable: false });
    return true;

};
```

I want to show logout alert only in home screen. In other screens I want to follow basic back navigation. Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach helped me to solve it.

In Homescreen I have included alert normally like in the question.

For the rest of the screens I have included goback() of navigation.

```
    componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.props.navigation.goBack());
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.props.navigation.goBack());
}
```

It achieved my requirement of showing alert in home screen and going back in other screens with this approach.

Comment: can you please explain what you exactly did

Answer (score 1):

I just added  clean up action in useEffect hook and it worked fine for me

```
useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBackButton);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBackButton);
    };
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

`backHandler` is applying to all your screen, it's because of using `useEffect` hook. Let me share my code where I had used `useFocusEffect` and `useCallback` method this works fine for me.

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
       
       Alert.alert('Hold on!', 'Are you sure you want to go back?', [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => null,
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          {text: 'YES', onPress: () => navigation.goBack()},
        ]);
        return true;
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, []),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to check for the current screen . in _handleclick add a check for routeName. There can be more solutions, but its difficult to tell by seeing only this amount of code

```
_handleback = () => {
   //instead of home screen, add your routeName when you are on home screen 
   if(this.props.navigation.state.routeName === "homeScreen")
    Alert.alert(i18N.t('alertHeader'), i18N.t('logoutqHeader'), [
        {
            text: i18N.t('yes'), onPress: () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('login'); }
        },
        { text: i18N.t('cancel'), onPress: () => { return true; }, style: 'cancel' },

    ], { cancelable: false });
    return true;
 }
};
```

Comment: if this code is in home screen. Will It work . basic back Navigation On other screens.

Comment: Please check it , you have to test it

Comment: what is your routename when you are on homescreen. Please check that
by consoling it

Comment: Checked it. Gave the same name. still alert coming in other screens

Comment: My approach working fine. any other way to handle this at only one page

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBack);   
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
}
```

But this has an issue, i.e, `componentWillMount` lifecycle method in React has been deprecated since React version 16.3.0

Hence, Approach #2

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}
handleBackButtonClick() {
    if(this.props.route.name === "login"){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App Intro");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
    } 
}
async componentDidMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}
```